# Errors loading multiple tags in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my `base.html`, I have quite a few custom simple tags that output things like the server time, and various variables on the sidebar of the site. Originally I had these tags in separate files:

```
templatetags
  policieschoice.py
  quantities.py
  servertime.py
  randomquote.py
  lowqolcs.py
```

I had a bunch of `{% load [x] %}` statements at the top of my `base.html`.

Everything worked fine. I then decided, because I was using all of these tags only in the base page, to refactor them and include most of them in a single file, replacing the mess of loads with a single load statement, and cleaning up a bunch of duplication in the various files.

```
templatetags
  basetags.py
```

I then planned to load everything with `{% load basetags %}`.

To my surprise, things stopped working. I made sure to remove duplicate imports and such, but I still received errors. The problem seemed to derive from most of my tags needing to accept context, as explained below.

If I used `{% load basetags %}`, then the page failed with the error `Invalid block tag: 'lowqolcs'`. This makes sense as lowqolcs is the first tag.

If I tried `{% load lowqolcs from basetags %}`, then the error was `'lowqolcs' is not a valid tag or filter in tag library 'basetags'`.

Now, lowqolcs requires context to work, so I tried {% load servertime from basetags %}. The error was once again `Invalid block tag: 'lowqolcs'`, implying that the servertime tag is valid.

lowqolcs:

```
def lowqolcs(context):

    request = context['request']
    try:
        world = World.objects.get(worldid=request.user.id)
    except:
        return ''

    if world.qol < -80:
        toreturn = '<style>body {font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;}</style>'
    else:
        toreturn = ''

    return mark_safe(toreturn)

register.simple_tag(lowqolcs, takes_context=True)
```

servertime:

```
def servertime():
    return v.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

register.simple_tag(servertime)
```

You can assume all the required imports are in place and the code itself is not failing, as I copied them from when they were individual files.

What's going on? Why can I not call the various tags from a single file whereas calling them from multiple files works fine? The requiring of context seems to be the key issue but I can't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you posted here is perfectly valid. The problem must be somewhere else.

Most probably, when you merged several files into one, you left several initialisations of the register:

```
register = template.Library()
```

Then your `lowqolcs` tag is being registered in the first register, which is later overwritten by another register.

Comment: Nope. I made sure to remove excess register initialisations.

Comment: Welp, I am officially retarded. Missed a sneaky one near the bottom. Many thanks. Will accept when able.